# Do end cities stop spawning after a certain distance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm pretty sure that I heard that end cities stop spawning after a certain distance, is this true? If it is true, does anyone have any numbers for what the said distance would be?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one. I've removed your secondary question from your post.

Comment: re: the deleted part of the question. It is possible (through commands) but inadvisable. The return gateway on the central island that opens after the dragon fight brings the player back to their spawn point - and so, with spawn in the End, you're unable to return to the overworld.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess you got the rumor of a true story that got corrupted in retelling.

*Everything* stops generating after a certain distance. Then starts again... and stops, and starts again...

Since 1.14 a bug has been introduced to End terrain generation: [MC-159283](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-159283).

If you travel 370,720 blocks away from the central island, you will find yourself at the edge. All terrain generation stops - there's only void. This void surrounds the generated terrain in a ring 153,568 blocks wide - normal generation, including end cities, resumes at 524288 blocks from the central island. Then stops again at some 642,000 blocks from the center, and this continues in increasingly narrower rings.

The video by AntVenom gives more details and footage of the phenomenon.

Comment: Ilmango also traveled there in survival mode as part of his peaceful series: https://youtu.be/p4YsPWN_Wfw

Comment: So, by Narrower, you mean at some point, void and city rings progressively increase in frequency such that, oh, I could see multiple in a single chunk?

Comment: @Malady They don't converge *that* fast. While the first void is over 150,000 blocks wide, the ones by world border are around 2,000 blocks, which is still well outside render distance, but easily crossable on Elytra (at a good cruising speed of 40m/s, the first void would take 3841s to cross, That's over an hour, 3 pairs of Unbreaking III Elytras, closer to 4 if you fly economically regarding rockets).

Answer (score 1):

End cities generate infinitely. There is no distance where they stop generating.

I'm guessing the place you heard this myth from was just having bad luck in finding end cities, and wrongly concluded that they stop generating after a certain distance.

To add some info with the prescense of @SF.'s answer, remember that computers can't do things in a real infinite way. When we commonly talk about something being infinite, it is important to note that nothing is actually infinite, but *theoretically infinite*. There is an end to everything, whether that just being bugs, crashes, data refusing to update, etc..